# Handle SettingsActivity onBackpressed() the same way as top bar back button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a SettingsActivity that has an "up" button included on the top bar. My AettingsActivity also has headers, that load proper settings fragments. By default, when I press the top bar "up" button, it closes the visible fragment and returns to headers, and closes activity if pressed on header view. Howeer, my phone "back" button works different - it just closes the activity. How ca i make "up" arrow and back button work the same way to keep my app consistent? Should I add onBackPressed to my activity, and if so, what should I put there?

My SettingsActivity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
}


private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}


@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
}


protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
    return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || NewsPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || OtherPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
}


public static class NewsPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_news);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


public static class OtherPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_other);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


}
```

This is a default code generated from Android Studio when creating new SettingsActivity, just with some changes made to suit my app

Answer (score 1):

You just need to override `onBackPressed()` method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
}
```

Comment: Can You please explain how can I check if a fragment can be deleted?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is writted on NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask and how you create fragments? Could you please update question to provide such informtation?

Comment: The problem is, that PreferenceActivity doesn't seem to have any fragment transaction and I can't figure out what exactly changes current fragment.

Comment: Sorry, was my fault, I thought that NavUtils is your class :)

Comment: I tried this function before, but it only finishes PreferenceActivity, without returning to the header view 1st :-(